# Ошибка в цикле

Tags: php

Собственно код, проблему описал в коментарии.

```
$img_path  = $_POST['gems'];
$img_value = array(
    Камень,
    Аметист,
    Изумруд,
    Рубин,
    Топаз
);
if ($img_path < 0) {
    $img_path = 0;
}
for ($j = 0; $j <= 4; ++$j) // Ошибка в этом цикле. Ругается, или на 1 строку цикла, или на if
    {
    if ($j = $img_path) {
        $img_selected[$j] = "selected";
    } else {
        $img_selected[$j] = "";
    }
}
echo "<select name='gems' size=\"1\">";
for ($j = 0; $j <= 4; ++$j) {
    echo "<option value=\"$j\" $img_selected[$j]>$img_value[$j]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: было бы неплохо, увидеть текст ошибки

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ($j == $img_path)//по идее
```

Comment: :D забыл о двойном равно, огромное спасибо

Comment: да и строки должны быть заключены в одинарные или двойные кавычки =)